# call this function with url parameter

Tags: php

How to call this function with url parameter

```
function test($str, $str_){

     if ($str == $str)
     echo "null";
     else
     echo "helloworld";
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: well as said cant send variables to function test($str, $str_), i need to send 2 variables with url link to the function.

Comment: I update my reply taking in care this new information. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
switch($_GET['cmd']) {
case 'hello':
    test($_GET['cmd'],'second_parameter_value');
}
```

The problem is that you aren't passing a value for the second parameter. I execute previous code and prints "helloworld"

**Second part:**

If your intention is to call the function using two parameters in the Url you can use the follow (I'm only modifying the important parts in your own initial code):

```
function test($str, $str_){

     if ($str == "null")
        echo "null";
     else
        echo "helloworld";
}

switch($_GET['cmd']) {
case 'hello':
    test($_GET['cmd'],$_GET['cmd2']);
}
```

and the Url to call this is: execute.php?cmd=hello&cmd2=hello2

Comment: Great! What a simple answer :D

Comment: I recommend use what DaveRandom suggest when you are developing:

"turn on display_errors in php.ini, or you can put the line ini_set('display_errors',TRUE); at the top of your script"

and remove this settings before final users use your scripts, to avoid show them possible important information about your scripts or server.

Comment: Power-Mosfet, answering your comment: your function is declared to receive two parameters, but you are calling the function passing to it only one. Which is your intention with the second parameter called "$str_"?

Comment: Im aware of this. I have modified my question, how to call test($str, $str_) with a url link

Comment: I modify the reply with "Second part" section, that is what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

The function is defined with two parameters, but you have only passed in one.

This will cause a fatal error and PHP stop execution - you should get an error message to this effect, if you are not it would be advisable for you to turn on [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in php.ini, or you can put the line `ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);` at the top of your script.

Try this:

```
function test ($str) {
  if ($str == "null") {
    echo "null";
  } else {
    echo "helloworld";
  }
}

switch ($_GET['cmd']) {
  case 'hello':
    test($_GET['cmd']);
    break;
  default:
    echo "No match in switch structure";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Init()
{
   if(isset($_GET['cmd']))
     {
       $command = $_GET['cmd'];
       switch($command)
       {
           case 'hello':
              test($command);
           break;
          default:
            echo 'hello world';
       }
    } else {
      echo 'Enter Command';
    }
}
function test($cmd)
 {
   echo 'Command: ' . $cmd;
}
Init();
```

Maybe this can help you

Comment: No explanation of your very modified code for an obvious newb?

Comment: Does anyone needs explanation for this??

Comment: I don't, but since the OP didn't clock the fact that he wasn't passing a second parameter to the function, he might. No offence meant, but a couple of comments in the code cost nothing... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$urlParams = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$functionName = $urlParams[2];
$functionName($urlParams);


function func1 ($urlParams) {
    echo "In func1";
}

function func2 ($urlParams) {
    echo "In func2";
    echo "<br/>Argument 1 -> ".$urlParams[3];
    echo "<br/>Argument 2 -> ".$urlParams[4];
}
```

and the urls can be as below
http://domain.com/url.php/func1
http://domain.com/url.php/func2/arg1/arg2